# Callback methods in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API server, that have to communicate with different applications on different platforms. And now I want to create a method that would be something like a callback: client application subscribes to it and waits until server fires a message.

**Example:**
Many users are waiting until new product will be available in store - they subscribe to this "event". When product arrives in store - every customer receives a message, which have to be handled in some case.

1. Users send a request "Subscribe"
2. Server receive a request "Product available!"
3. Server sends every user a message with product details.
4. User's application processes the message

I tried to find some information about callbacks or duplex in ASP.NET Web API, but the one advice -  it's better to use WCF for this approach.

#### Solutions

- In every client application create something like timer, that every N seconds sends a request "Is product available?" until gets "false". When the response will be true - send a message "Get product details". It's causes a lot of traffic and if there will be many clients with these timers - it would be something bad, isn't it?
- Create a small callbacks-server (maybe WCF). But in this case would be a lot of problems with communication between this server and apps on different platforms.
- Maybe there are some solution in ASP.NET Web API, that i missed.

If you have some ideas how i can solve this problem, please give me an advice.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you want push notifications from your server - which, in this case, can be achieved by combining SignalR with Web API.

Brad Wilson has a great example on this:

1. code here - https://github.com/bradwilson/WebstackOfLove
2. NDC Oslo talk explaining all this - http://vimeo.com/43603472

In short, whenever you add new item to the Web API, you can notify all the connected (subscribed) clients:

```
public void PostNewItem(ToDoItem item)
        {
            lock (db)
            {
                // Add item to the database
                db.Add(item);

                // Notify the connected clients
                Hub.Clients.processItem(item);
            }
        }
```

SignalR will invoke the `processItem` function on the client.

Alternatively, you might want to look into JavaScript SSE and Web API `PushStreamContent` but that is much more low level and SignalR abstracts a lot of this type of stuff for you so it might be more complicated to deal with.

I blogged about this approach here http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/native-html5-push-notifications-with-asp-net-web-api-and-knockout-js/