# Connecting a windows forms application to a C# web service?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, api, rest

I've created two applications, one windows forms application in Vb.net and another web service application in C# and MVC.

Whats the best way of connecting the 2. The windows forms app is for attendance checking, so the application will currently need a user to input attendance information and write to a local access database.

I was thinking of creating a REST API for my web service which would allow the windows forms application to call the data and add any new check ins that have occurred. I'm wondering though how would my windows forms application know when to call the REST API for the web service when new data is added?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "What is the best..." questions are subjective and so cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much figured out by you own. 
You can either use WCF or Web API, both will work fine for your purpose. If you want to know the difference, please read this [link](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/JI2X050413-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-API-and-WCF-REST-and-Web-Service.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Would the windows application know when data has been added to the web service by some sort of trigger or would it have to check it at a specified time for an update, if a Web API was to be used?

Comment: Yeah, You have to implement some sort of pulling method to check the changes. If you like you can use SignalR or Service bus to do some kind of pushing from web api side. Here is answer for SignalR. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184690/callback-methods-in-asp-net-web-api